# Using Bootstrap modal popup

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have recently started using bootstrap modal popup. It looks great except for one annoying thing I need to create a whole div hierarchy for using the modal popup. e.g.

```
<div class="modal fade">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body&hellip;</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
</div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

I would prefer a way of passing header content, body content as argument rather than creating this whole structure. The basic problem I have with structure is if tomorrow Bootstap renames/add a new class I will need to change it in N places and also there is lot a repetition of code which does not seems to be right.

I am missing some trick here or is to be done this way.

Comment: you can have one model template and change `header` data , `body` data and `footer` data in run time

Comment: I'd say this depends on what, if any, frameworks you're using. Different ones have different ways of handling this scenario.

Comment: @lxonal I am using Jquery & Bootstrap Js

Comment: @CerlinBoss I was also thinking on the same lines. I thought there is some built in mechanism that I am missing. Will try doing the template route

Comment: this could come in handy - http://bootboxjs.com/

Comment: What about on the server side? Just plain html pages or some kind of framework there?

Comment: @Ixonal I am using thymeleaf, spring mvc integration

Comment: Looks like you could use the include functionality to abstract this into a single call. http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html

Comment: Hi Rachit. Are You Using PHP ?

Answer (score -1):

You could use a function which would add the templating to your specific content, could you ?